# what shall I do to avoid different date formats and if it applicbleto use dd/mm/yy in all browsers with different date formats

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have the following in the code first

```
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? starting_date { get; set; }
```

I have the following in frontend

```
<label>Starting Date:</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.starting_date)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.starting_date)<br />
```

I have the following in script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#starting_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
```

what shall I do to avoid different date formats because the validation detecting the PC date format which I can't expect it or detect it, if it applicable to use dd/mm/yy format in all browsers with different date formats, or detect the current date format to change datepicker format

Comment: Use a jQuery datapicker plugin. (and note that if you using mvc's validation using `jquery.validate.js`, then it validates dates in MM/dd/yyyy format unless you reconfigure it - it does not use the devices date format)

Comment: I changed all format in my code to be mm/dd/yy after that I changed the PC date format from mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy I got the same validation error  msg

Comment: note:- I use VS 2015 and SQL server in the same PC

Comment: What validation error? And the formats on the client and server must match, otherwise you need to post the date in iso format (yyyy-MM-dd), or use a custom ModelBinder.

Comment: ValidationMessageFor error , because is a different format I use mm/dd/yy but the browser which I test is dd/mm/yy therefor what I actuly need to avoid any browser format and using one format e.g. mm/dd/yy or detect the current browser  date format to be able to set datepicker format

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for your help I used iso format till I find solution to do it by custom Model , if you have any example for custom model Binder for this case please send it to me and thank you again